# getElementsByClassName produces error "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I have several `textboxes` with the class `output`. I would like to be able to print their values as a plain HTML list in a `div` with `ID` `combined`. Right now, I have the following code:

```
function doCombine() {
    document.getElementById('combined').innerHTML =
    document.getElementsByClassName('output').value + ",";  
}
```

Yet, when I run the function, i get the error message `undefined`,. When i add a `[0]` before `.value`, it works, but only the value of the first `textbox` is showing up. I read somewhere that `[i]` will show all the values, but that doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: GetElementsByClassName returns a NodeList, you need to iterate through the result

Comment: The reason is that document.getElementsByClassName returns an array of all the elements with the class name "output". so you need to tell withe index that which element you want to access.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### getElementsByClassName

*Returns a **set of elements** which have all the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.*

So you should be doing

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('output');
var combined = document.getElementById('combined');
for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
  combined.innerHTML += elements[i].value + ",";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object, not a single element (notice the plural in the name of the function). You need to iterate over it, or use an array index if you just want to operate on the first element it returns:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0].value + ","
```

Answer (score 2):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a *set* of elements. You need to iterate over it:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("output");
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
  combined.innerHTML += elems[i].value + ",";
}
```

That's why adding [0] works, because you are accessing the first object in this set.

Answer (score 1):

This function will return ALL the elements with that name, because"name" attribute is not unique, so it returns an list (nodeList, to be exact).

To print out ALL the values, you need to add a loop. Something like

```
  var finalvar = "";
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('output');
  for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
         finalval = finalval + arr[i].value;
  }
  document.getElementById('combined').innerHTML = finalval
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName will return a set of elements. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName#Summary. Some browsers return `HTMLCollection` and some browsers return `NodeList`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection#Browser_compatibility But they both have `length` property and `item` method in common. So you can iterate like this.

```
function doCombine()
{
    var listOfOutputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('output');
    var combinedItem = document.getElementById('combined');
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfOutputElements.length; i += 1) {
        combinedItem.innerHTML += listOfOutputElements.item(i).innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName returns an NodeList. So you won't be able to call the value method on it. Try the following:

```
function doCombine() {
    var combined = document.getElementById('combined');
    var outputs = document.getElementsByClassName('output');

    for(var i=0; i<outputs.length; i++){
        combined.innerHTML += outputs[i].value + ',';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FM3qH/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doCombine()
{
var combined = document.getElementById('combined');
var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('output');
    var nodeListLength = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0;i<nodeListLength;i++) {
        combined.innerHTML += nodeList[i] + ',';
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: You're adding nodeList[i], that's adding the `toString` value of an element, instead of the value.