# Calculating price from quantity

Tags: javascript

I making the shops for my site, and but I can't understand why this conde don't wont to work...Here's the code:

```
<script>
function Price() {
    var Quantity = document.getElementsByClassName('BUY')[0].value;
    var Total = Quantity * 20;
    if (!IsNan(Total)) {

        document.getElementsByClassName('Total').innerHTML = Total;
        document.getElementsByClassName('Quantity').innerHTML = Quantity;
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('Total').innerHTML = "Invalid number";
        document.getElementsByClassName('Quantity').innerHTML = 0
    }
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<input style="margin-top:1%;" type="text" name="BUY" class="input" maxlength="1000" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Buy " onchange="Price()" required>Price for <span class="Quantity">0</span>Views:<span class="Total">0</span> Satoshis<br>
```

From this code I expect a print of the calculation based on the quantity but  the code don't work and I get no errors...

Comment: "Won't work" is not a useful problem statement. What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: maybe you should use `parseInt(Quantity)` before multiplying?

Comment: missing `parseInt` around `Quantity` (value returns string). Undefined element with `class="BUY"`. Collection of elements (`byClassName`) has no `.innerHTML` method. Etc.

Comment: Your input is text.
Make sure all your variables are actually numbers before preforming math operations on them (TL;DR- They are not on your case)

Comment: also, you should use `isNaN`, not `IsNan`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: in this code nothing, there are a lot of basic mistakes

Comment: Please do some basic debugging, that will solve many of the small mistakes here

Comment: getElementsByClassName is not "BUY" but "input"

Comment: If it's not too late, I'd advise you against using the same text you display to users as source for maths and calculations of any sort. You should always keep your number in properly typed variables and convert the result to text for mere display purposes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you have worng class name in the script that's why it is not working.

*corrected code*:(**Just copy & paste it .works changed class into ID**)
Because using classname it is not fetching the correct value instead it assigns Quantity as `undefined`  [refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289907/getelementsbyclassname-produces-error-undefined)

```js
                function price(){
                    var Quantity=document.getElementById('buy').value;
                    
                    var Total=Quantity*20;
                    if(Total != 'NaN'){
    
                        document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML=Total;
                        document.getElementById('Quantity').innerHTML=Quantity;
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML="Invalid number";
                        document.getElementById('Quantity').innerHTML=0;
                    }
                }
```

```html
<input style="margin-top:1%;" type="text" name="BY" id="buy" maxlength="1000" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Buy " onkeyup="price()" required/>Price for 
    <span id="Quantity">0</span>
    Views:<span id="Total">0</span>
    Satoshis<br>
```

Comment: hey, *man*, I didn't downvote you, but if an answer doesn't solve the problem it gets downvoted. This case is particular in that, since OP didn't do any basic debugging, you have to correct *a lot* of stuff. Good luck.

Comment: Also, don't complain, it isn't *manly*. If you correct your question and solve everything, chances are the downvoter will retract their downvote.
EDIT: if it was not clear, I'm using "man" a lot because you did first, and I'm just teasing

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementsByClassName('BUY')` will search for elements having class 'BUY', but ur input has class 'input'