# Cannot set property of undefined error on button press

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm trying to change the background color of a div element on button press but I'm getting the error **Cannot set property 'BackgroundColor' of undefined**. The event handler for the button is inside the window.onload event. I thought at that point every element inside the html document would be loaded, but apparently not.

Here is the code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="random">This should become unreadable</div>
    <button id="button">Click me!</button>
    
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.getElementsByClassName("random").style.BackgroundColor= "black";
    
            });
        }
    </script>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("random")` returns a HTMLCollection, not a single element - therefore `document.getElementsByClassName("random").style` is `undefined` ... perhaps `document.getElementsByClassName("random")[0].style ....`

Comment: also, I think it's backgroundColor not BackgroundColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code segment.
the issue is **document.getElementsByClassName("random")** returning an array of elements.So you should select one element from that array and get the style of that element.
And **BackgroundColor** should be **backgroundColor**

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="random">This should become unreadable</div>
    <button id="button">Click me!</button>
    
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.getElementsByClassName("random")[0].style.backgroundColor= "black";
    
            });
        }
    </script>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this out - [getElementsByClassName produces error "undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289907/getelementsbyclassname-produces-error-undefined)

Another alternative could be this.

```
<body>
    <div id="random">This should become unreadable</div>
<button id="button">Click me!</button>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById("random").style.backgroundColor= "black";

        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the script as follows and try again:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="random">This should become unreadable</div>
    <button id="button">Click me!</button>
    
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.querySelector(".random").style.backgroundColor= "black";
    
            });
        }
    </script>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into comments by @Bravo, `document.getElementsByClassName("random")` returns a HTMLCollection, not a single element - therefore document.getElementsByClassName("random").style is undefined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="random">This should become unreadable</div>
    <button id="button">Click me!</button>

    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        document
          .getElementById('button')
          .addEventListener('click', function () {
            const button = document.getElementsByClassName('random');
            for (let index = 0; index < button.length; index++) {
              const element = button[index];
              element.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
            }
            // if you will have only one element with class=random or if you only want to apply style to the first element with class=random, then 
            // button[0].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
            // in your case, you should add an id to the element and use id as the selector
          });
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```